# Transformar una imagen Byte[] a otra imagen en formato WEBP también en Byte[] con "org.sejda.imageio"

Tags: java, imagen, formato, byte

Trabajo en lenguaje Java y tengo una imagen en Byte[] que puede ser de algún formato como JPG, PNG, etc.

Necesito desde ahí obtener una imagen en Byte[] en formato WEBP.

He encontrado una librería "org.sejda.imageio" que genera archivos WEBP.

He visto ejemplos trabajando con File pero yo necesito trabajar con Byte para poder guardar la imagen WEBP en la base de datos.

La nota donde explica como trabajar con File es la siguiente:

https://genuinecoder.com/java-webp-image-read-save-tutorial

Quizás alguien sabe como cambiar esa función para trabajar con Byte[] y no con File.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185807/webp-support-for-java/65998284#65998284 espero te sirva de algo

Comment: En Java no sé cómo se hace, pero lo típico es convertir un Byte[] a Stream, y luego el Stream a file.

Comment: @Yussef en Java para pasar de Byte[] a archivo es mediante la clase `ByteArrayOutputStream` y mediante composicion se pasa a un `FileWriter` (es decir se le pasa como parametro del constructor), como seria eso relevante aca?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Lo que pasa es que editó la pregunta  (no había puesto ningún código), el partió con el problema que tenía una imagen en Byte[], y encontró una librería que le pedía un File (seguramente como parámetro)

Comment: Si asi es. Agregue un nuevo codigo ahora que no da error pero el Array que genera esta vacio.

Comment: Perdonen por la edicion, es que sigo investigando y voy contando las novedades que tengo.

Comment: Nada que perdonar, lo lógico es que vayas editando si vas avanzando y si encuentras la solución, recuerda que puedes responder tu propia pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue la solucion:

```
   byte[] imageBytes = ...;

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(bais);
    ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByMIMEType("image/webp").next();
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    writeParam.setCompressionType(writeParam.getCompressionTypes()[WebPWriteParam.LOSSLESS_COMPRESSION]);
    writeParam.setCompressionQuality(0.70f);
    
    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bi, null, null), writeParam);
    ios.close(); //importante que este antes que baos.to..
    byte[] imageBytes2 = baos.toByteArray();
```

Dejo aca también los import ya que cambiar alguno hacia que no funcionara:

```
import com.luciad.imageio.webp.WebPWriteParam;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream;
```